# Use of Modernizr.load

Tags: javascript, jquery, modernizr

I am using Modernizr for conditional loading of resources. My code is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="stylesheet/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jQuery/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/stickyheader/jquery.fixedheadertable.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="javascript/stickyheader/defaultTheme.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/modernizr/modernizr.2.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Modernizr.load([ {
        // If browser supports touch
        test : Modernizr.touch,
        //Load iPad related resorces 
        yep : [ 'javascript/ipad-default.js', 'javascript/touchscroll.js', 'javascript/ipad-scroll.js',
                'javascript/mobile.js' ],
        // Load common resorces 
        load : ['javascript/ipad-default.js']
    } ]);
</script>
```

This is working fine. But I am wondering if I can load all resources in `Modernizr.load` when I test for `Modernizr.touch`.

To be clear I want to load all resources within `Modernizr.load`.

*How can I do this? And is this a good approach?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. It definitely is a good approach to use a resource loader for a web application. However, I found the page rendering to be a little shattering when loading all CSS through Modernizr.

```
// You can load CSS just like JS
Modernizr.load("stylesheet/style.css", [
  {
    test : Modernizr.touch,
    yep : [ 'javascript/touchscroll.js', 'javascript/ipad-scroll.js', 'javascript/mobile.js' ],
    load : [ 'javascript/ipad-default.js' ] // No need to specify this in 'yep' too
  }]);
```

Because `Modernizr.load` is built on `yepnope.js`, the [yepnope documentation](http://yepnopejs.com/) is a little more interesting for resource loading than the Modernizr tutorials. If you don't mind yet another framework, I can recommend [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/). This one really helps to decouple and load your components.