# jvectormap switch Marker size on Ipad

Tags: ipad, jvectormap

I would like to know, if it's possible to change the size of a marker, only for iPad users?
I tried the following:

```js
if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) ||
    (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPod') != -1)) {

    markerStyle: {
      initial: {
        fill: '#ff3300',
        stroke: '#383f47',
        r: 22
      }
    }

} else {

}
```

But doesnt work :S Is there a way to change the size of a marker for iPad users?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Any errors you get? For now I see that your code is just syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Hy Bjorn, i´m not very familar with jquery & co.
i get these error: SyntaxError: missing : after property id

thanks

Comment: Then I think the answer here would be "Hire someone who does".

Comment: ahhh thats the way to learn, anyway.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use a feature detection library, something like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/). They have [examples here](https://gist.github.com/855078).
Then depending on the users device, you could load a different, more suitable `jvm.WorldMap` with bigger markers, instead of the normal map.

Have a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566914/use-of-modernizr-load) which shows you how to load in other resources if the browser supports touch.

Hope this helps!